# How to apply scrollbars when data size exceeds the min-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I want to apply scroll bar in my application dynamically when data in the div exceeds the height provided. How it can be fixed using jQuery.

Comment: This is not a Grails related question

Comment: I have created my application on grails and I need to apply dynamic scrollbar using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use fixed height on the wrapper div and set overflow to scroll.
ie.

```
#wrapper-div {
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#wrapper-div').height() < $('#inside-div').height()) {
        $('#wrapper-div').css('overflow', 'scroll'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Applied but not working i need dynamic scrollbar which appears only when data in div exceeds height not always.

Comment: then you can use jquery to change the css attribute dynamically. see my  edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use css overflow property as auto

```
<div id="myDiv">
Your dynamic sized paragraph goes here.
</div>

<style>
#myDiv
{
overflow:auto;
}
</style>
```

Overflow:auto; will add scrollbars automatically if the content exceeds the height you specified.